# Join two tables in Php

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables

Table 1 category

```
Id    name      img   
1   appliances   
2   books
```

Table 2 products

```
ID  name des  price  cataegory sub  img
1  TV    lcd  125     1        tv
```

I am trying to join the two tables that in category in table 2 till get the name from table 1

This is my code

```
    $sql = "SELECT p.id, 
                   p.name,
                   p.description, 
                   p.price,
                   c.name,
                   p.sub
            FROM products p
            JOIN category c on products p = c.id
            ORDER by p.id
            ";

    if($query =  mysql_query($sql) or die())
    {
        while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {   echo "<tr id='id'>";
            //echo "<td>".$result['img']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result['name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result['description']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result['price']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result['category']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result['sub']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }       ";
```

Comment: great work. but what is your question?

Comment: If you look at the code its easy to see where the error is and hence what the question is. I considered a similar comment but realised I could actually give an answer quicker than I could give sarcasm.

Comment: `JOIN c.category on products p.category = c.id`

Answer (score 1):

Add category name to the columns returned by select query:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id, 
                   p.name,
                   p.description, 
                   p.price,
                   c.name,
                   p.sub,
                   c.name AS category_name       -- Category name
            FROM products p
            JOIN category c on p.category = c.id
            ORDER by p.id
            ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename field name in output:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id, 
                   p.name,
                   p.description, 
                   p.price,
                   c.name AS OTHER_NAME,
                   p.sub
            FROM products p
            JOIN category c on p.category = c.id
            ORDER by p.id";
```

And then get **OTHER_NAME**

Comment: can i use like c.category ?

Comment: You can try, but I never heard about that syntax. What does mean `c.category`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT p.id, 
                   p.name,
                   p.description, 
                   p.price,
                   c.name,
                   p.sub
            FROM products p
            JOIN category c on p.cataegory = c.id
            ORDER by p.id
            ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.name,
  p.description,
  p.price,
  c.name,
  p.sub
FROM products p
  INNER JOIN c.category
    on products p.cataegory = c.id
ORDER by p.id
```

Use inner join for specific results